# Use a lightning component within a dashboard?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dashboard

Is the currently possible to build a lightning component and then use it within a dashboard? If so how do I do it.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to this is **No**. There is no way as of today that you can add a lightning component in a Dashboard. There is this idea [Ability to add Lightning Components to Dashboards](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lITwQAM) open to allow this feature.

What you can do is instead create a custom tab and use that as a dashboard where you will be able to put your custom lightning components.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose a Lightning Component in a Classic Dashboard, but it will not work in Lightning. As Jayant [says](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/256749), you would want to vote on that idea. To get this working in Classic, you simply need to create your component, create a dependency app, create a Visualforce page, and finally add the page to your dashboard as a new component. See Using [Lightning Components in Visualforce Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm). This is only a temporary workaround and should not be relied upon heavily.